# Responsive HTML and CSS mind map / boxes connected with lines

Tags: html, css

I would like to create via HTML and CSS similar mind map which is supported at least IE 10. I saw few tutorials via canvas, svg but I get stacked.

Is there any way to create some boxes connected via lines in some easy way.
And to do this even harder responsive?

[image: html css mind map]

Comment: Canvas or SVG as you pointed out. Show some code from one of those methods you've tried and we can help you overflow your stackedness.

Comment: First thing I can tell you is for such Idea you would definitely need to use JavaScript as well. 
I would suggest you using d3.js which is really great library to manipulate SVG or Canvas using JavaScript.

Comment: GREAT GUYS with this I found that d3.js will fit my needs, I found http://bl.ocks.org/jdarling/2d4e84460d5f5df9c0ff and here diagonal connector will do what I need. I will play with it ;)